# Optimization Problem involving traces of SU(2) matrices

Tags: optimization, lie-groups, trace

Given some unitary matrices mit determinant one $U_1,\dots,U_n\in \mathrm{SU}(2)$, I would like to determine an/the element $U\in SU(2)$ such that
$$f(U) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\mathrm{trace}(UU_k)\right)^2$$
is maximal.

My approach so far: any infinitesimal transformation of $U$ can be written as $U\mapsto \exp(i\epsilon H)U$ with $H\in \mathfrak{su}(2)$ a hermitian matrix with trace zero. So I can get the condition
$$0 \stackrel{!}{=} \frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}f(\exp(i\epsilon H)U)\vert_{\epsilon=0} = 2i\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{trace}(UU_k)\mathrm{trace}(UU_kH)\hskip 1cm \forall H\in\mathfrak{su}(2)$$
$\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is a $3$-dimensional Lie-Algebra, so this condition consists of $3$ independant equations. They are only quadratic in (the matrix components of) $U$ so it should be possible to solve for $U$

Comment: Are you sure it is max and not min? If it is min then your question is a nonlinear analogue of the Euclidean center of mass, so at least for matrices $U_j$ close to each other, the function you are minimizing is convex rather than concave. Also, if you identify $SU(2)$ and the 3-sphere, then $tr(AB)$ can be expressed in terms of the spherical distance between $A$ and $B^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes it is max. My goal is to generate random elements of $SU(2)$ with probability distrubtion $\frac{1}{N} \exp(\beta f(U))$ (with constant $\beta>0$) with the rejection-method. That means I generate $U\in SU(2)$ uniformly and then accept the proposal with probability $\frac{\exp(\beta f(U))}{\exp(\beta f_{max})}$ where $f_{max}$ is some upper bound on $f$. Using the naive bound $f(U)\le 4n$ works correctly but makes the algorithm very inefficient.